# How to create directive with angularjs binding expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to convert below code to dynamic code using angular directive or any other angular way.

one Directive:

```
<view-partial></view-partial>
```

**view-partial.html**

```
<div id="layoutFormation">
    <div ng-repeat="container in layoutJSON.layoutInfo.containers" class="row form-container x_panel tile">
    <div class="x_title nopadding"><label class="container-header">{{(container.headerText == " ") ? "" : container.headerText }}   <a href="#" onclick="onCollapseExpandClick(this)" class="collapser-expander-button expanded"></a></label></div>

    <div number-of-rows="{{ container.table.numOfRows }}" number-of-columns="{{ container.table.numOfColumns }}" class="x_content col-md-12 col-xs-12 collapse-expand">

        <div ng-repeat="columnNumber in range(container.table.numOfColumns)" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 column">

            <binding-control-block ng-repeat="rowNumber in range(container.table.numOfRows)" row-number="{{rowNumber}}" column-number="{{columnNumber}}"  style='margin-bottom: 12px;' />

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here binding-control-block is another directive that directive with binding code already i'm doing in dynamically. Only  thing the above partial page also i need to convert dynamically. I think I have to add all the above view-partial code in another directive. just i need any example or idea how to create directive with binding expression. Please any one help me to achieve this. If any clarification need please message me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `number-of-rows=` doing?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev - number-of-rows and number-of-columns will get value dynamically for example number-of-rows -3  number-of-columns-2

Comment: Looks more like the case for Angular filter.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev - can you please read once again my requirement. I hope this time you will get my requirement.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev - I am waiting for you reply.